# Plotting multiple Longitude and Latitude points on a Map?

Tags: excel, google-maps, maps

I have several thousand locations in longitude and latitude that needs to be plotted on the map. Is there any way to plot them? Or do you think there are software to help? These locations are now in an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Try [Batch Geo](http://batchgeo.com/)

Comment: export the excel to CSV and import the CSV into a fusionTable

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but for what it's worth, I did create a Userform that creates a .kml google earth file from excel. It's fairly feature packed, what with metadata, and directional arrows. In case it's useful to anyone--> http://amitkohli.com/?p=53